# Upload file to s3 and get back Public URL

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a JSON file using boto3 Python on s3 Amazon. The file is uploading successfully, but I am not getting the returned public URL.

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError
from credential import ACCESS_KEY , SECRET_KEY



def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                      aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False


uploaded = upload_to_aws('temp_file.json', 'feed-crawler', '0output_test.json')
```

Comment: You should be able to construct the public URL from the bucket name and the key you used. Something like: `https://<amazon-regional-endpoint>/<bucketname>/<key>`

Comment: https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/feed-crawler/0output_test.json , but i don't think it is working :(

Comment: Your object in s3 should have public-read ACL set - so that anyone with the URL should be able to read it